# MYSQL INNER JOIN syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, inner-join

I have been trying to fix my issue on this since morning :)

I have two tables. table1= post table2=users. now I need to extract data from both tables. searched how to use INNER JOIN, found some codes. I run the query inside phpmyadmin and it works fine here is my sql query

`SELECT post.topic_id, post.category_id, post.topic_id, post.post_creator, post.post_date, post.post_content, users.username, users.gender, users.id
FROM post INNER JOIN users
ON post.post_creator=users.id
WHERE post.post_creator=users.id and post.topic_id=19
ORDER BY post.post_date DESC`

but when I use this sql query inside my php it gives me error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN users ON post.post_creator=users.id ORDER BY post.post_date ASC' at line 1

below is my php code

```
<?php
             include_once './forum_Scripts/connect_to_MySql.php';
             $cid = $_GET['cid'];
                if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
                    $logged = " | <a href ='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a new topic</a> ";
                }else{
                    $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum.";
                }

             $tid = $_GET['tid'];
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
             $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){

                 echo "<table width='100%'> ";
                 if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
                     echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 'post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'\" /> | <a href = 'http://amaforum.net63.net/'>Return to Forum Index</a><hr />";
                 }else{

                 echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td>";}

                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                         $sql2 = "SELECT post.topic_id, post.category_id, post.topic_id, post.post_creator, post.post_date, post.post_content, users.username, users.gender, users.id"
                                 . "FROM post INNER JOIN users ON post.post_creator=users.id ORDER BY post.post_date ASC" ;
                         $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                         while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
                        {   
                             echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border:2px solid #000000'><div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
                                 by ".$row2['post_creator']." - ".$row2['post_date']."<hr />".$row2['post_content']."</div></td>"
                                     . "<td width='200' valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>"
                                     . "<input id='".d_text."' type='".text."' name='".the_creator."' value='".$row2['post_creator']."' >"
                                     . "echo '$user_info' "
                                     . "</td></tr>"
                                     . "<tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr> ";
                        }
                     $old_views = $row['topic_views'];
                     $new_views = $old_views + 1;

                     $sql3 = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1 ";
                     $res3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die (mysql_error());
                     }
                     echo "</table>";
                 }else{
                 echo "<p>This topic does not exist</p>";

             }
             mysql_close();
             ?>
```

I can get it to work and I really need help from you guys..

Thanks in advance

Comment: need a space here: `users.id"` to be `users.id "` Specifically: `$sql2 = "SELECT post.topic_id, post.category_id, post.topic_id, post.post_creator, post.post_date, post.post_content, users.username, users.gender, users.id "
                                 . "FROM post INNER JOIN users ON post.post_creator=users.id ORDER BY post.post_date ASC" ;`

Comment: You're missing a space in the query : `users.idFROM`

Comment: Provide some space after `users.id  "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem (I've just added the space that was missing when you concatenated the two lines of your sql query):

```
<?php
             include_once './forum_Scripts/connect_to_MySql.php';
             $cid = $_GET['cid'];
                if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
                    $logged = " | <a href ='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a new topic</a> ";
                }else{
                    $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum.";
                }

             $tid = $_GET['tid'];
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
             $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){

                 echo "<table width='100%'> ";
                 if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
                     echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 'post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'\" /> | <a href = 'http://amaforum.net63.net/'>Return to Forum Index</a><hr />";
                 }else{

                 echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td>";}

                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                         $sql2 = "SELECT post.topic_id, post.category_id, post.topic_id, post.post_creator, post.post_date, post.post_content, users.username, users.gender, users.id "
                                 . "FROM post INNER JOIN users ON post.post_creator=users.id ORDER BY post.post_date ASC" ;
                         $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                         while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
                        {   
                             echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border:2px solid #000000'><div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
                                 by ".$row2['post_creator']." - ".$row2['post_date']."<hr />".$row2['post_content']."</div></td>"
                                     . "<td width='200' valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>"
                                     . "<input id='".d_text."' type='".text."' name='".the_creator."' value='".$row2['post_creator']."' >"
                                     . "echo '$user_info' "
                                     . "</td></tr>"
                                     . "<tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr> ";
                        }
                     $old_views = $row['topic_views'];
                     $new_views = $old_views + 1;

                     $sql3 = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1 ";
                     $res3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die (mysql_error());
                     }
                     echo "</table>";
                 }else{
                 echo "<p>This topic does not exist</p>";

             }
             mysql_close();
             ?>
```

To avoid issues like this in the future, it's always good practice to log the sql that's being executed in your code somewhere, or even just echo it onto the web page while testing. That way you'll very quickly debug issues like this.

Comment: thanks @xQbert  Simon Woolf Benoit Garret and Abhik Chakraborty.. it is now working fine..